# How to Call nodejs API from ajax call in cross domain enviroment and get response by returning data back to the Ajax

Tags: node.js, ajax

> Help me in this i m new in nodejs and API calling through Ajax

```js
//Node Function to be call via ajax 
app.get('/Employee', function (req, res) {
  var  obj = {};
       // res.sendFile(__dirname + "/" + "Employee.html");
    var mysql = "Select * from employeelogin";
    
        con.query(mysql, function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(result);//
            obj = result;

    });
//return Obj
    res.render('/Employee', obj);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
function Get_Emp_record() {
    $.ajax({
       // url: '/Employee/GetDetails',
        url:'http://127.0.0.1:8081/Employee',
        data: {},
        method: 'GET',
        async: false, 
        crossDomain: true,
        processData: true,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json',
        jsonpCallback: 'callback', 
        success: function (data) {
           
            alert(data)
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
            //show error message
            alert('text status ' + textStatus + ', err ' + err)
        }
    });
}
```

> Thank you in advance

Comment: Set `CORS` headers. You could use the `cors` module. It works great with express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple solution for this, would be to use "cors" module.

**installation**

```
npm install cors
```

**usage:**

```
var cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors());
```

Thats all you need to do.

**Note:** some HTTP requests might be preflighted, "preflighted" requests first send an HTTP request by the OPTIONS method to the resource on the other domain, in order to determine whether the actual request is safe to send.
To enable pre-flighting, you must add a new OPTIONS handler for the route you want to support:

```
app.options('/route', cors()) // for a particular route
```

To enable pre-flighting for all routes just use:

```
app.options('*',cors()) //for all routes(include before other routes)
```

more on pre-flighted requests : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests

Comment: yes @Anurag it is hitting the API  by adding given line of codes, but not returning the response JSON to ajax sucess

Comment: @Eshu is the problem solved? If not please share the server code also

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate vibhor1997a's comment,

Install `cors` package in your project by issuing the below command,

```
$ npm install cors
```

You can include in your application like this,

```
var express = require('express')
```

And you can enable the `CORS` like this,

```
app.use(cors());
app.get('/Employee', cors(), function(req, res) {.....
```

Hope this helps!